# Why isn't my program printing the right values?

Tags: c, linux, clang

I wrote this program that should calculate the sin of a number, and when I input the values 1.57 on the x value and 0.00005 on the tolerance value, it should say: "The sin of 1.57 is 1.000003.", but instead it prints: "The sin of 1.57 is 0.000000." I've tried adding random floats (like multiplying by 1.0) on all of the formulas, but nothing. I'm running a clang compiler on a linux environment, if that helps. any help would be appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int fatorial(int n){
    int f=1, t;
    for(t=n;t>1;t--){
        f=f*t*1;
    }
    return f;
}

float sen(float x, float tol){
    float res=0, aux=0, auxi;
    int n=0;
    for(n=1;auxi>tol; n++){
        res=res+(pow(-1,n+1))*((pow(x*1,2*n-1))/fatorial(2*n-1));
        aux=res;
        if((aux-res)>0){
            auxi=aux-res;
        }
        else{
            auxi=res-aux;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
int main(){
    float yo=0, tol, res;
    printf("What's the value of x? ");
    scanf(" %f", &yo);
    printf("What's the value of the tolerance? ");
    scanf(" %f", &tol);
    res=sen(yo, tol);
    printf("The sin of %.2f is %f.\n", yo, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never enter the `for` loop in your `sen` function since your checking if `auxi` is greater than `tol`, but auxi is never initializied! Also your `n` in the for loop doesn't make sense for the condtion

Comment: uau...i feel...ridiculous right now... thank you for your help -_-

Comment: Glad that i could helped you! (BTW: made a answer)

Comment: Despite the clanger (geddit!) I'm giving you Kudos for telling us what you tried and what platform you're running on. That often matters though not in your case! We've all been there. There's no shame!

Comment: this printf format converter: %.2f is only going to print 2 places after the decimal, so it would never print: '0.000000'  rather it would print: '0.00'  The format converter, for your desired output would be: %8.6f

Comment: BTW: a sin runs from 0 (0 degrees) through 1 (90 degrees) for the first (upper right) quadrant so, are you saying that the input value 'x' is actually the degrees (or radians)?

Comment: this line: f=f*t*1; There is no need to multiply by 1  and any constant should be written like 1.0f

Comment: i have another printf right after that one, which is the one which should print the number with all the zeros, I don't really know if it's on degrees or not, since it was my teacher who told me to calculate it like this, sorry =s as for the 1, it originally was 1.0 (in a desperate attempt to force a float everywhere), and when I changed it, i must have forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never enter the `for` loop in your `sen` function since your checking if `auxi` is greater than `tol`, but `auxi` is never initializied!

Also your `n` in the for loop doesn't make sense for the condtion.

Comment: thanks, the n is just for the factorial, i needed to increment it with every loop. it still isn't returning the right value, but it's getting closer i guess... XP

Comment: @GordonRamsay Your condition(`auxi>tol`) is every time false! Since you never assgined a value to auxi!

Comment: i know, i already changed that. now it prints "The sin of 1.57 is 1.570000." I'm considering starting from scratch, it's getting too confusing...